# Design pattern, ordered set of string transformations

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a design pattern or strategy to deal with the following scenario:

3 different strategies for transforming strings through various different methods: decoding, decrypting, removing sections of the string at specific places, converting to array and so on.

Each strategy use  different combinations of the possible transformation to achieve its end result on the string.

I have a class responsible for each transformation for example: Decoder, Decrypter, Splicer and so on. And I have 3 concrete classes that have the transformers it requires injected into its constructor.

Is there an accepted design pattern for this problem. I feel that there is a more elegant way to achieve this but cannot see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the **Chain of Responsibility** Pattern using *Command* objects or the **Command** Pattern.

I could write some code but WikiPedia does it better. [Chain-Of-Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

The idea is you construct *Command* Objects (Decoder, Decrypter, etc.) and arrange them in the order of their responsibility.

The Chain-Of-Responsibility comes in by their ordering.

For your three different strategies, you are describing the pattern already.  The best one their is, the **Strategy** Pattern. [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Some psuedo language:

```
interface Action {
    public void execute()
}

class Decoder extends Action {

    public void execute() {
        I'm decoding
    }
}

class Decrypter extends Action {

    public void execute() {
        I'm decrypting
    }
}
```

For each different implementation of your Decrypter or Decoder simply implement a new version of Decrypter or Decoder.  The `Action` implementation associated with into your class will be executed on the call to `execute()`

That's it.  At least I think this is what you're describing.

Comment: does make sense i think yes.  Can commands have different return types?  I am wondering if one command returns a string and one returns an array

Comment: The signatures must be consistent since you are calling an interface.  If you want to return different types you might consider returning something in a passed in parameter/object.

Comment: See `ICommandResult` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796988/how-to-perform-multiple-operations-in-under-single-transaction/43802711#43802711). This way you can send anything back from `Execute` keeping signatures consistent.

Comment: That's cool.  So you'd be returning the same object with a consistent interface.